# Rebuilding firmware back to binary file

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, linux, embedded

I used Binwalk to extract firmware files,  extracted content include 2 folders and one binary file.

```
squashfs-root
_351C.extracted
351C
```

Squashfs-root contains file system, '_351C.extracted' folder contains security certificates (.crt). Don't know what is '351C' binary file (2.96 Mb).

Now I need to rebuild firmware back to binary image (.bin). How to rebuild this into binary firmware image? I tried use Firmware Mod Kit to extract fw, but it old, fails to run on my LTS 16.04 due missing some dependencies.

The FW [file](https://yadi.sk/d/Nw47salo3Qncdy).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the firmware format. If it was pure squashfs, without any additional header, just generate the new firmware file out of your set of files via mksquashfs https://elinux.org/Squash_FS_Howto#Creating_and_using_squashed_file_systems
Otherwise, you'll need to append header/footer to the squashfs file to make it look like the original firmware.

Comment: For more specific, I added an actual FW file. Is there other tools or methods to add header and footer and rebuild to original binary?